# Am I required to update to target Android 9 (API level 28)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I received an email from Google stating that I am required to target Android 9 (API level 28) and after November 1, 2019 I will no longer be able to submit updates unless the app is updated. I am confused as to if this means my app will remain in the App Store or not. The app that is published has very few features and is extremely simple so I never actually update anything on it.

Below is the email I received from Google today.

[image: fdas]

Comment: Take the email at face value.  You will not be able to submit updates at your current API level, but this does not mean that your app will stop working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what I assumed the case would be. I'm fine with my app being live and not on the latest API level.

Comment: This is not an ideal question for SO. However, I got the same email today. I think the app should still be there and if you submit any new update, this will require you to update your API level as well.

Comment: New apps or updates to existing apps needs to target SDK api 29.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email means that I am no longer able to upload builds targetting API level 28 but currently live builds will remain live and will require no changes.